# A Trivial Second Order PDE?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} = \frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$$

To find the second order derivative

$$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}$$

we apply the chain rule such that

$$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial S}\Big[ \frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\Big] = -\frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} +\frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\Big[\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\Big] $$

I am struggling to solve the seemingly trivial part

$$\frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\Big[\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\Big] $$

The solution should read...

$$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} = -\frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}$$

Comment: You're interested in finding a solution to the PDE : $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} = \frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$$ ?? If so, what's the point behind $\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}$ ?

Comment: And also, $S$ is a variable ?

Comment: I'm struggling to express $$\frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial}{\partial}\Big[\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\Big] \equiv \frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial ^2 V}{\partial x^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(\frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{S} \color{blue}{\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S \partial x}} \\
&= -\frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{S} \color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right)} \\
&= -\frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{S} \color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)} \\
&= -\frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{S^2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}
\end{align}